# Web scraping for the website which was secured by Incapsula?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, incapsula

I am in need to scrape the data from the website [here](http:///http://www.vignanam.org/veda/gayatri-mantram-ghanapatham-english.html). This was protected by Incapsula. I have already done two approaches and also used the techniques which were given by Stack Overflow users.

**APPROACH 1**:

```
from incapsula import IncapSession

headers = {'Host': 'www.vignanam.org',
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/7.0.540.0 Safari/534.10',
           'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
           'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
           'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
           'Connection': 'keep-alive',
           'Cookie': 'visid_incap_1642409=B+YoelHCSKKN5z/Phs0zXCsF9VsAAAAAQUIPAAAAAACXaWvcNDXdMzcOky/SvffB; incap_ses'
                     '_715_1642409=kyFvSyJuuBVpNuh+aTHsCSsF9VsAAAAAKV6TIWTPSZmb+mOZWeuNHA==',
           'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1'}

session = IncapSession()
response = session.get('http://www.vignanam.org/index.htm#&panel1-1', headers=headers, bypass_crack=True)

print response.text
```

**APPROACH 2:**

```
from mechanize import Browser
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = Browser()

browser.open('https://www.incapsula.com/blog/how-incapsula-protects-against-data-leaks.html')

print browser.response()

soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.response().read(), features='html5lib')

print soup
```

Both approaches are producing the same results.

**RESULT/OUTPUT**

```
<html> 
<head> 
<META NAME="robots" CONTENT="noindex,nofollow"> 
<script src="/_Incapsula_Resource SWJIYLWA=5074a744e2e3d891814e9a2dace20bd4,719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3"> </script> 
<body> 
</body>
</html>
```

How to break this and scrape the data from there? Is any other programming languages to overcome this?

Comment: Approach 2 is sending request to wrong url.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Sure. I will improve me from questioning in the StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

This :

```
import requests

requests.get('http://www.vignanam.org/index.htm#&panel1-1').text
```

worked fine for me.

I didn't see any kind of incapsula protection and it didn't block my request.

(`curl http://www.vignanam.org/index.htm#&panel1-1` worked too in bash)

Returns :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">\n<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">\n<head>\n<title>Vaidika Vignanam - Vedic Chants, Siva, Vishnu, Devi\nStotrams, Annamayya, Tyagaraja, Ramadasa Keerthanas in Sanskrit, Hindi,\nTelugu, Tamil, Kannada, Malayalam, Gujarati, Bengali and Oriya</title>\n<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="css/vignanam.css"/>\n<link rel=stylesheet href="css/anythingslider.css" type="text/css" media=screen />\n<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" rel=Stylesheet />\n<link rel=stylesheet href=aqtree3clickable.css />\n<link rel=stylesheet href="css/glowtabs.css" type="text/css" media=screen />\n<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv=Content-Type />\n<meta name=keywords content="vedas, vedic chants, shiva stotrams, vishnu stotrams, \n\t\tdevi ......
```

Comment: Did you get the output as the complete page's HTML file? Can you please show your output. Because still, I am getting the same output as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Whether you are using linux?

Comment: Cannot show you the entire output as it doesn't fit in a stackoverflow message

Comment: @AravindhThirumaran Gave you the beginning of the output and it doesn't look like what you got. I don't think that Linux made any difference here.

Comment: Did you have any ideas, why I am only getting this output? In my office, everyone is getting the same output which I got. We used various IPs too. Still, I am unable to get the output.

Comment: If you can scrape means, will you send me all mantras in CSV file in the English language

Comment: Which country you are from?

Comment: @AravindhThirumaran I cannot scrap for you. I'm from France. I cannot help you more, I think that when a website protects itself from scraping, it means that you shouldn't scrap. I was just mentioning that maybe there was an error because I could launch the request fine.

Comment: @CorentinLimier it implements an dynamic blocking algo, it means that it not blocks any request ..but watching you and then start blocking.   The current answer is wrong

Comment: @Reishin current answer is wrong or current question is incomplete ? :)

Comment: OP question is pretty much clear - how to get content of the site "reliably" behind the incapsula. However SO is not a "help bypass or crack things" site, answer is not simple as curl http://example.com.   It's better to close the question completely.